# How can I get the argument type of an SFC component's event?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-script-setup

Say I have an SFC component with a `save` emit:

```
// ChildComponent.vue
const emit = defineEmits<{
  save: [data: { new: Row[]; removed: Row[] }];
}>();
```

If I want to use the `new` & `removed` in a parent component I would do this:

```
// ParentComponent.vue
<ChildComponent 
  @save="($event) => {
    performAPIRemove($event.removed); // TypeScript correctly infers `$event` type
  }"
/>
```

However, I want to define the event callback as a named function. How do I get the type of the child component's emit?

```
// ParentComponent.vue
// Something along the lines of...
function saveCallback(event: typeof ChildComponent.emits.save) {
  performAPIRemove(event.removed)
}
```

Comment: At this point this makes sense to define separately a type you reuse in other places. It's possible that it can be extracted from ChildComponent type but that's a workaround

Comment: @EstusFlask yeah, that's my backup plan. I just didn't want to define exported types for every component's emits, methods etc. I guess that might just be the correct way and I'm overthinking this.

Comment: This would be a problem with third-party comp but for your own one you can write it the way it's convenient to use. Types are exported per need basis. This serves a good purpose for maintenance because this indicates they are potentially used the way you do this

Comment: @EstusFlask That's a good point, though - how would one go about doing this with a third-party component? Most libraries would export their own types, but what if it doesn't? Would the best option be to just define your own type based on what the component emits?

Comment: Generally I'd try to search in Vue source code if there's utility type to extract event types from component type, there could be some . But the compsI used exported relevant types including events, this looks like a good strategy for a third-party lib, exporting it like the answer shows would be ok. If it weren't, I doubt a lib were typed good enough to contain event types. In contrast to props, typed events aren't a standard.

Answer (score 0):

I,

You can create an interface in a ,ts file ex :

```
export interface ChildEmits {
  new: Row[];
  removed: Row[];
}
```

Then, in your child component, you can use this type :

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
  save: [data: ChildEmits];
}>();
```

And you can type your callback parameter like this :

```
function saveCallback(event: ChildEmits) {
  performAPIRemove(event.removed)
}
```